# JavaScript cross domain access from subdomain in iframe

Tags: javascript, cross-domain

Parent page is located on site.com. I have page located on sub.site.com which will be included on the parent page via an iframe. Per https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy this should be possible by having the sub.site.com page update its domain to site.com. However I still get access denied errors due to same origin policy when I try this.

site.com:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body><iframe src="http://sub.site.com"/></body>
</html>
```

sub.site.com:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
    function setupPage() {
    try {
        var oldDomain="current iframe domain: ";
        oldDomain = oldDomain.concat(document.domain);
        alert(oldDomain);

        document.domain='sakai.rutgers.edu';
        var newDomain="new iframe domain: ";
        newDomain = newDomain.concat(document.domain);
        alert(newDomain);

        var parentDomain="parent domain: ";
        parentDomain = parentDomain.concat(parent.window.document.domain);
        alert(parentDomain);

    }
    catch (err) {
        var e = "Caught error: ";
        e = e.concat(err.message);
        alert(e);
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onload=setupPage()>
<p>Test Page</p>
</body>
```

When I load the parent page, the first two alerts show the domain being reset as expected. However, when the script attempts to access `parent.window.document.domain` the following error is thrown (in Chrome):
"Caught error: Blocked a frame with origin "http://sub.site.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame."

What did I miss?

Answer (score 0):

I think in the code you might want to use

```
parentDomain = parentDomain.concat(document.domain);
```

instead of

```
parentDomain = parentDomain.concat(parent.window.document.domain);
```

in the first case I guess it has available to the current window so it will get the text and concatenates it. if you need to access the parent window use something like

```
parent.window.frames.documents............
```

hope that helps.I am no guru Myself but I had these situations before and that technique have taken away the problem.